# What is the value of $\nabla\times (\vec a\times \vec r)$?

Tags: vectors, divergence-operator

> Given that $\vec r=xi+yj+zk$ & $\vec a$ is a constant vector then what is the value of $\nabla\times (\vec a\times \vec r)$ ?
>
> a) $\ -2\vec a\quad $ b) $\ 2\vec a\quad $ c) $\ 3 a\vec r\quad $ d) $\ -3 a\vec r\quad $

My try:

$\nabla\times (\vec a\times \vec r)$

$=\vec a(\nabla\cdot \vec r)-\vec r(\nabla\cdot \vec a)$

$=\vec a(3)-\vec r(0)$  (because divergence of a constant vector $\vec a$ is zero.)

$=3\vec a$

But my answer doesn't match any options given above. My teacher says option (b) is correct answer but i don't know how.

Please correct me if i am wrong & help me solve this question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You [missed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_2) two terms:
$$
\nabla\times (\vec a\times \vec r) = \vec a(\nabla\cdot  \vec r)-\vec r(\nabla\cdot \vec a)
+(\vec r\cdot\nabla)\vec a-(\vec a\cdot\nabla)\vec r \\
= \vec a(\nabla\cdot \vec r)-(\vec a\cdot\nabla)\vec r=3\vec a-\vec a=2\vec a.
$$

Note that for the last term we use:
$$
(\vec a\cdot\nabla)\vec r=(a_1\partial_x+a_2\partial_y+a_3\partial_z)r
=(a_1,a_2,a_3)=\vec a
$$

---

[Added later by request.]
Since $\vec a$ is a constant vector, one has
$$
\nabla\cdot \vec a = 0,\quad (\vec r \cdot\nabla)a=0,
$$
which explains why the second and third terms vanish.

Comment: I would suggest you indicate that the variable '$a$' is a vector by making it bold, as in $\mathbf {a}$

Comment: but vector triple product is  $\vec a\times \vec b\times \vec c=\vec b(\vec a\cdot \vec c)-\vec c(\vec a\cdot \vec b)$  . So why there are four terms in vector triple product $\nabla\times (\vec a\times \vec r)$?

Comment: @WinterSoldier: I was sloppy. I edited the post by adding the vector arrow.

Comment: @jeanneclement: $\nabla$ is a differential operator, not a constant vector. So your identity does not work. Check the linked Wikipedia article. Think about the 1d case: $\frac{d}{dx}(fg)=(\frac{d}{dx}f)g+f(\frac{d}{dx} g)$ but you have $a(bc)=(ab)c$ where $a,b,c$ are three real numbers.

Comment: @user587192: OK, if it's vector differential then why is $\nabla\times (\nabla\times \vec F)=\nabla(\nabla\cdot \vec F)-\vec F(\nabla\cdot \nabla)$ ?

Comment: @jeanneclement $a\times (b\times c)$ and $(a\times b)\times c$ are different and one should not write $a\times b\times c$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product. Also, the way to prove the identity you just mentioned is not by either of these two identities.

Comment: @user587192:  How did you evaluate $\vec r(\nabla\cdot \vec a)$ &
$(\vec r\cdot\nabla)\vec a$ in your answer. please explain?

Comment: @jeanneclement: post edited. Note that $\vec a$ is a constant.